# Javascript/Jquery loop elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to make a quiz for a school a friend of mine works.
The students get to see 4 word and 4 sentences and they need to drag the right word to the sentence that fits with it.

I am making this inside the browser with jQuery and MySQL, this so that the teacher is able to view who did the assignment and who didn't.

The teacher want's to have 4 questions per page and then you click the next button and you see what you did wrong/good and move on to the next 4 questions. At the end I need to write it to the database.

Currently I am walking through the answer with the following jQuery code.

```
 if ($("#answer1").data("answer") == $("#question1").text()) {
   $("#question1").css("background","#0F9");
   good++;
 } else {
   $("#question1").css("background","#903");
   mistakes++;
 };
```

I was thinking about loading all the questions at once and hiding/showing them when you click the next button to prevent double questions and to make it easy to remember the good/wrong answers.

Now I want to make the looping through the code above dynamic. So I though about putting it in a for look like this.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if ($("#answer" & (i+page)).data("answer") == $("#question" & (i+page)).text()) {
     $("#question" & (i+page)).css("background","#0F9");
     good++;
   } else {
     $("#question" & (i+page)).css("background","#903");
     mistakes++;
   }; 
 }
```

Ofcourse the  **& (i+page)** part isn't working at all. (the page increases when you hit the next button by 4). Is there some way to make this possible in javascript/jQuery or do I need to chance my approach completely?

Comment: What is 'page' a reference to? Are you trying to concatenate `#answer` + `i` + `page` into a selector string?

Comment: Off-topic, but: `$('[id^=question]').each(function() {$(this).text($('#answer'+this.id.replace(/\D/g,'')).data("answer"));});` Run in the console, this code instantly answers all questions correctly. NEVER store the answers in the browser.

Comment: Can the student just do a "view source" on this quiz and see all the right answers?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you probably just ruined the day of the one kid in the class that knows how to view source

Comment: Try `+` instead of `&`

Comment: use js string concatenation rather than coldfusion

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am still a bit new to javascript and I now need to think of a different approach. Thanks for the warning haha! Think I will have to build in a check with PHP that will see through this.

Comment: @Ennui the page variable increases every time a student goes to the next page. As I explained in the last bit of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation in *JavaScript* is done with the `+` operator. The `&` is a bitwise *AND*.

*JavaScript* also has

```js
'foo' + 0; // "foo0" i.e. String + Number = String
0 + 'foo'; // "0foo" i.e. Number + String = String
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace all `&` with `+` in the code you gave.